# How to get specific info for all users?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I get the `kaarsen` array out of my Firebase database of every single user?

[image]

Comment: Why do you think that's an array? You can access it directly at /myT3.../kaarsen. Also, please include your Firebase structure as TEXT please, no images - that way we don't have to retype it in our answer. Also, please make an effort to try to write some code to accomplish the task and let us know where you get stuck. Finally, review this super helpful article: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be nesting different types of data, which is a big anti-pattern in the Firebase Database. When you read data from Firebase, you always read entire nodes. So in your scenario you either read the entire user, or you don't read them. You cannot retrieve just the `kaarsen` node for each user. This is one of the many reasons why Firebase recommends against nesting different types of data.

In your case it seems best to split the kaarsen int a top-level node:

```
users
  <uid>
    email: ...
    geboortedatum: ...
    naam: ...
kaarsen
  <uid>
    ...
```

With this structure you can get the `kaarsen` for all users by accessing `/kaarsen`.

Comment: Oh alright, but can I get all elements of the kaarsen-array then for all users?

Comment: Yup, if you attach a listener to `/kaarsen` you get it for all users.

Comment: Hello, would you have any idea of the solution to this problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43597578/how-to-call-a-function-once-orderbychild-is-done-running    ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

ref.child("users").child(userID!).child("kaarsen").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
// Get user value
let value = snapshot.value as! Array
arrayOfKarsens.append(value)

// ...
}) { (error) in
print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```